# Can I work on cakephp 2 and 3 on same xamp server on my pc

Tags: cakephp

I need to use cakephp but I need to use PHP 7 (min. PHP 5.5.9). Currently I am on xamp windows and using PHP Version 5.5.19 . I still need cakephp 2.x work for now until i upgrade so how do i create in cakephp2 and 3 on my current setup? Can I install cakephp 2 and 3 on the same xampp server?

Comment: I cant find the solution still

Comment: both install as described in related documentation.